# Iterate array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have in my controller a function to make a search filter.

The search parameter is obtained from a select field of my twig template.

The selected option is passed to the controller to see where results are with that value.

The query result is returned in JSON format.

```
public function categoryAction(Request $request){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $category = $request->request->get('category');

    $contentCategory = $em->getRepository('PublicartelAppBundle:Content')->findByCategory($category);

    $filterContent = new JsonResponse();

    $filterContent->setData([
        'category_result' => $contentCategory
    ]);

    return $filterContent;
}

$('#selectCategory').on('change', function () {
    var optionSelect = $(this).val();
    $.post("{{path('playlist_category') }}", {category: optionSelect}, 
    function (filterContent) {
        var result = filterContent.category_result;
        console.log(result);
    }, 'json');
});
```

This return in console:

> [Object, Object, Object]
>
> O: Object
>
> 1: Object
>
> 2: Object
>
> lenght: 3

The amount of items returned depends on the number of items found with that category.

If I do the following could iterate each of the elements.

```
for (var content in filterContent.category_result){
    console.log(content, filterContent.category_result[content]);
}
```

And return in console this:

> 0 Object {}
>
> 1 Object {}
>
> 2 Object {}

But I want to access the 'name' property of each object.

How could I say to want to access the object name property , or at least iterate one by one one each?

Comment: you was almost good. try `filterContent.category_result[content].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `findBy` repository method return a Doctrine `ArrayCollection` populated with the entity value. For translate it as a valid JSON you can iterate it and translate in a simple array as follow in the Controller class:

```
    $contentCategory = ....

    $contents = array();

    foreach($contentCategory  as $elem)
        $contents[] = array(
            'name' => $elem->getName();
            ....
        );


$filterContent = new JsonResponse();

        $filterContent->setData([
        'category_result' => $result
    ]);    

    return $filterContent;
```

You can also take into account to use a Serializer as http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

Hope this help

Answer (score 4):

You can log `filterContent.category_result[content].name` if it's the appropriate property.

Comment: category_result is an entity object of Content, and 'name' is a property of Content. 
But when i make this that you tell me, the console return is:  'undefined'..

Comment: Please show me the exact contents of filterContent.category_result

Comment: You can see content in the image  the reply on the post of 'mmm'.

Comment: I don't see such an image. Please paste the contents into a Github gist and share it in the comments here if you would like me to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 1):

try this to see where is "name" :

```
for (var content in filterContent.category_result) {
    console.log(content);
    for (var i in filterContent.category_result[content]) {
        console.log(filterContent.category_result[content][i]);
    }
}
```